# Search and replace references to local files in html file?

Tags: php, regex, templates

We're building a PHP application which allows the user to upload a zip file with an index.html file and associated images, js, css files - which serves as a "template" for their page.

To use the index.html file through our application, we must replace all occurrences of code like this:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg">
```

with

```
<img src="~~~TEMPLATEPATH~~~/images/image1.jpg">
```

And then save it on our server.

When displaying this template to the web-user, ~~~TEMPLATEPATH~~~ is replaced with the proper path where the template file's index.html is located on our server.

All "file references" must be preceded with this variable.

Can someone suggest the ideal way of doing this - the regular expression that would do this (in php or a shell script we can call)? Note: Naturally, we dont want to insert this variablename when there is an absolute path, eg:

```
<img src="http://www.example2.com/images/image1.jpg">
```

---

Is our method (process) the right way of "allowing" templates? Is that how other sites function?

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio - but is that the proper way templates are made? Am I going about it correctly?